# Android Math.sqrt returns 0

Tags: java, android, sqrt

```
this.promien = Math.sqrt(Math.abs((this.x * this.x) + (this.y * this.y)));
```

And x=0.965(...) y=-15.285(...). This abs was added later, when I was trying to fix the problem. this.promien is always 0, and I have no clue why. I restarter Android Studio, didn't help. Is there something I couldn't see?

```
public class Pomiary {

    public Pomiary() {

    }


    public Pomiary(double x, double y, double z, Date data, int seria) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.data = data;
        this.promien = Math.sqrt(Math.abs((this.x * this.x) + (this.y * this.y)));
        this.suma = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y) + Math.abs(z);
        this.seria = seria;


    }
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    int id;

    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING, format = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    Date data;

    @DatabaseField
    double x;

    @DatabaseField
    double y;

    @DatabaseField
    double z;

    @DatabaseField
    double suma;

    @DatabaseField
    int seria;

    @DatabaseField
    double promien;
```

And I'm debugging this app, that's how I know it's 0. Also request to database returns 0, when x and y are not equal 0.

[Debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngbh1.png)

Where I instantiate:

```
if (MainActivity.pomiary) {
double promien  = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(X,2) + Math.pow(Y,2));
                    Pomiary pomiary = null;
                    try {
                        pomiary =
                                new Pomiary(X, Y, Z,
                                        dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date())), iloscZapisanychSeriiWBazie);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

And x,y,z are values from magnetometer

Comment: what is the type x and y are defined in?

Comment: what type is promien

Comment: How are you discovering the result is 0?

Comment: You need to show us a complete, verifiable example. I can assure you that `Math.sqrt` and `Math.abs` both work.

Comment: whats the point of `abs` if you are squaring values anyways

Comment: Are you sure your debugger is not simply displaying the value of `promien` before it is assigned? Have you tried logging the value of `promien` after the assignment?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure, you can see it on the pic I added. Also, I tried to log the value, but nothing is showing up.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are instantiating these objects? Is it possible you are passing 0's without realizing it? Throw a breakpoint in there and make sure everything is what you think it is when you are instantiating your objects.

Comment: How do you even get android studio to show the variables in the code like that? For me it shows them in a variables view at the bottom of the screen. I think it's just displaying the value of `promien` before it is assigned. If you do  `Toast.makeText(this, pomiary.promien + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` in the activity class, I'm sure it will show a value that is not `0.0`.

Comment: It;s not that easy to make Toast in this case because it's not Acitivity class and has no context. I don't know what happend, I have change nothing, but now it works, and the output is visible next to the variable. I don't know what's going on, but I hope it's not the only time it's working...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `abs` since `z * z` is always nonnegative and you're adding two nonnegatives. You can't be getting zero because one of the products is negative. It would be good to see how you're creating this object.

If I define `Pomiary` like so:

```
public class Pomiary {
  double xx;
  double yy;
  double zz;
  Date dataa;
  double promien;
  double suma;
  int seria;

  public Pomiary()
  {

  }
    public Pomiary(double x, double y, double z, Date data, int seria) 
    {
        this.xx = x;
        this.yy = y;
        this.zz = z;
        this.dataa = data;
        this.promien = Math.sqrt(this.xx * this.xx + yy * this.yy);
        this.suma = Math.abs(x) + Math.abs(y) + Math.abs(z);
        this.seria = seria;
        System.out.println(this.promien);
    }
```

And call it like so:

```
public class JavaLab23{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Pomiary p = new Pomiary(3,4,5,null,0);
      System.out.println(p.promien);
    }

}
```

I get nonzero output.

Comment: debug mode says neither x nor y is 0

Comment: What's value of `this.promien`? (Note that I edited my answer.)

Comment: this.promien is 0, that's the problem. I uploaded pic from the debug mode in my 1. post

Comment: I added this to class, where I get the values for Pomiary class:

double promien  = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x,2) + Math.pow(y,2)); 
In debug mode I get error: Cannot find local variable 'promien'... Is it somehow connected with that issue? I tried to restart computer, the phone, and unistall the app. Nothing happend...

Comment: `promien` is not a local variable. It's a field of an object whose type is `Pomiary`. Refer to my recent edit to see that `this.xx` and `x` refer to different locations in memory. So if you don't define `promien`, then `this.promien` refers to a field in "this" instance of `Pomiary` that does not exist. You should post the code that produced the output in your Answer.

Comment: Note also that I accidentally left off `this` before the first `yy` in the line defining `promient` but there was no problem. That's because `yy` is a field of `Pomiary` and `this.yy` and `yy` refer to same memory by default. That's why I changed all the field definitions to `xx`, etc. To illustrate the difference between `this.x` and `x`, for example. The former is a field, the latter is value of first parameter. So the original `this.x = x` assigned value of parameter `x` to the first field of `Pomiary`. Now `this.xx = x` does the same thing.

Comment: When I asked if you extended a class, I should have asked if you have any `import` statement that migt be relevant to solving why you suddenly got correct output.